# С чего начать изучение русского языка простыми словами

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Давайте представим после апокалиптическое изолированное русско-говорящее  общество, например 10 тысяч человек. Каждый из них знает словарь Ожегова наизусть и алфавит, умеет читать и писать, но не знает ни одного правила русского языка. Имеется огромная библиотека, но нет ни одной книги, чтобы узнать правила.
Кроме того, никто не знает слов: подлежащее, сказуемое, падеж, союз, междометие, предлог, суффикс и т. д. и т. п.
Давайте им придумаем 20-30 правил русского языка, ведь детей всё-таки придется учить читать и писать?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это литературное предложение пофантазировать на тему языка.

Answer (score 2):

Значит, словарь остался, а правил нет? Прекрасно! **Придумывать ничего не надо, потому что правила не придумывают.** Их можно вывести из наблюдений за реальной письменной и устной речью.

Соберите с десяток самых умных представителей общества. Изучите фонетику и сравните ее с алфавитом, чтобы установить звуко-буквенное соответствие. Это и будет **первая група** правил (способы обозначения мягких звуков, гласные после шипящих, мягкий знак поле шипящих, разделительные знаки, особенности употребления парных гласных Э/Е).

Потом изучите отличие реального произношения слов от их записи, проведите анализ (слабых позиций) — безударные гласные в разных морфемах, звонкие и глухие согласные, мягкие согласные и т.д. Это будет **вторая группа** правил.

**Третья группа правил** касается формы написания (слитно, дефис, раздельно). Что обозначает каждая форма? Подумайте и составьте правила для различных тем.

Параллельно должна работать группа по изучению **грамматики**.

Знаки препинания изучайте **по интонации**, но окончательная формулировка делается по грамматическому принципу.

Удачи вам!

**Кстати, это вовсе не шутка, а реальная методика изучения правописания**. Ведь в  чем смысл правила? Это выбор между двумя (реже тремя) вариантами. К примеру, в слове ***слон*** неоднозначности нет, поэтому и правила этому слову не нужны. Надо понять, когда возникает неоднозначность и попробовать самому решить проблему. А потом сравнить с уже известным решением, которое называется **правилом.**